# converting simple xml node into R dataframe get empty values

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

Having a very simple xml I want to export to dataframe in R.

```
<root>
 <source>
  <sourceId value="8556"/>
 </source>
<content>
  <DESCRIPTION value="0"/>
  <SORTED value="290"/>
  <ANNULATION value="34"/>
  <RECORDING value="5665"/>
  <TOLOCK value=""/>
  <FUTURE value="categorical"/>
 </content>
</root>
```

I retrieve the node I need this way:

```
library(XML)
xmlDoc <- xmlParse("path-to-file", useInternalNode=TRUE)
df <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(xmlDoc,"//content"))
```

but dataframe has only columns with no value at all. So I guess I am wrong in some step.

```
> df


 DESCRIPTION SORTED ANNULATION RECORDING TOLOCK FUTURE
1                                                      
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ DESCRIPTION: chr ""
 $ SORTED     : chr ""
 $ ANNULATION : chr ""
 $ RECORDING  : chr ""
 $ TOLOCK     : chr ""
 $ FUTURE     : chr ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, xml processing is very dependant on the file. So you have to struggle with it as there is no silver bullet.

In your case, just iterate throug names and values from tags this way assuming you want it in one row (not very pretty I must say):

```
doc <- read_xml("my.xml")

content <- xml_find_first(doc,".//content")

values <- xml_children(content) %>% xml_attr("value")

names <- xml_name(xml_children(content))

df <- data.frame(mstrix(ncol = length(names), nrow = 0))

df <- rbind(df, values)

colnames(df) <- names
```